# How to get a selected object within other stuff?

Tags: extjs, selection, extjs4

I have a multiselect grid where I can get schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

there is an object called data, I want to get a field within the data; lets say school_name

How I'll do it?

I've tried

```
schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection().data
schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection(data)     
schools.datagetSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

they did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Ext.each` to iterate over the array of records..

```
Ext.each(schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection(), function(record, index, allRecords) {
    console.log(record.get('school_name');
});
```

Comment: 'have to' is a bit strong. Sure, `Ext.each` is a convienient thing, but not the only solution.

Comment: afaik, `Ext.each` skips functions added to the array prototype object, so it's more compatible for their framework

Answer (score 0):

This:

`schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].get('school_name')`

should give you a 'school_name' field from first row selected (which is also a first record in selection).

To iterate over all selected rows do:

```
var selectedSchools = schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
for (i in selectedSchools) {
  console.log(schools[i].get('school_name'));  //this will log school name to firebug console - you can do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: I need to see all the selecteds. [0] shows only the first selected :/  In firebug I can see all the selected shools under data object with schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection() but how to do it with your code now?

Comment: `schools.getSelectionModel().getSelection()` returns an array of models. You need to iterate over it to get access to individual rows. See updated answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use `for` to iterate over an array in Ext, use `Ext.each` like I've shown below

Comment: Agreed, makes things look more consistent.